# angular.js with ng-model using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have a dictionary of objects with some duplicate ids like this:

```
var groups = {"0": "attributes":[{"id":2, "name":"abc"}, 
                            {"id":5, "name":"xyz"}], 
              "1": "attributes":[{"id":2, "name":"abc"}]}
```

I want to fetch this group into input text fields of form like this

```
<div ng-repeat="group in groups">
 <input type="text" ng-model="group.value"/>
</div>
```

Its working fine if I have all the distinct ids but I want the input fields with duplicate ids to be attached with same ng-model, so that if one input is filled then another one gets filled automatically.
Searched almost everything but couldn't come up with any solution. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The HTML standard requires elements to have unique IDs to be valid. Use a class to select multiple elements using a shared selector. You could write some code to have each element with the same ID have the same ng-model value.

Comment: Had to write a function as you suggested. Finally problem solved. Thanks :)